# ngModel innerHTML works in p tag but not in input tag angular2

Tags: angular, innerhtml

In one of my angular2 application, I want to show the innerHTML of the model in the input field which has a model is attached to it.

```
<input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="studentCategory" [innerHTML]="studentCategory"/>
```

the value of studentCategory is coming from data base which has some '& #174;' values. which is directly showing up in the text boxes, rather it should show a register symbol

i can easily show this in the following way

```
<p [innerHTML]="studentCategory"/></p>
```

but not in input which has model attach to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you exactly want to do? What HTML do you want to show in input? It's an input box, you can place a placeholder in that or you can fill it with a default value, but with innerHTML what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` refers to the content of the HTML tags.

A [<p>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) tag may contain  phrasing content. An [<input>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) tag, however, must be empty. It may not have any child elements nor text content.

`<p [innerHTML]="'hello'"></p>` resolves to `<p>hello</p>`. This is legal HTML. But `<input>hello</input>` is not valid. (`<textarea>hello</textarea>` would be valid).

You need to ensure that the HTML-entities are already unescaped before you assign the string to your ngModel variable studentCategory.

Comment: edited my question for better understanding. My problem is that the student category is the model which has values coming from database. I am just showing the value in the text box. so i cant change the value.